# How to Apply Category Filter to Pagination

Tags: theme-development, pagination

I am using **Wordpress 4.3** and **WPML** plugin. I used category filter on theme, front page of site only displays posts in "**English**" category. Category id is **62**.

Code is below:

```
<?php
                $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
                $page = isset($wp_query->query['paged']) ? (int)$wp_query->query['paged'] : 1;
                $count_post = 9;
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => $count_post,
                    'offset'           => ($page-1) * $count_post,
                    'category'         => '62',
                    'orderby'          => 'date',
                    'order'            => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'        => 'post',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
                );
                $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
                ?>
```

Originally the theme didn't contain pagination so I implemented something like this by comparing the code to another theme:

```
<div class="row text-center">
            <hr>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination m30-0">
                    <?php
                    if($page > 1) {
                        $i = $page - 1;
                        $url = "href='../../page/$i/'";
                    ?>
                    <li>
                      <a <?=($page==$i?'':$url)?> aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                        for($i = 1;$i <= $maxpages;$i++){
                            $url = "href='".($page >= 1 ? "../../": "")."page/$i/'";
                            ?>
                            <li class='<?=($page==$i?'active':'')?>'><a <?=($page==$i?'':$url)?>><?=$i?></a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    if( $page + 1 <= $maxpages ) {
                        $i = $page + 1;
                        $url = "href='".($page >= 1 ? "../../" : "")."page/$i/'";
                    ?>
                    <li>
                      <a <?=($page==$i?'':$url)?> aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
```

As expected resulting pagination displays more pages than I have in English category. I have about 4 pages, but pagination displays 4 more pages which are empty. I think pagination is counting posts in other languages as well.

What would be the correct way to implement category filter to pagination as well?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `'suppress_filters' => false;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113715)

Comment: Ok, I'll update. This should be answer.

Comment: Why would this solve OPs issue?

Comment: Because it tells WPML to query posts only from current language.